# How to retrieve the N first rows AND the N last rows in only one request?

Tags: postgresql

Let's say we have a huge query like this:

```
SELECT id, quality FROM products ORDER BY quality
```

Is it possible to retrieve the N first rows AND the N last rows of the results, *without performing two requests* ?

What I want to avoid (two requests):

```
SELECT id, quality FROM products ORDER BY quality LIMIT 5;
SELECT id, quality FROM products ORDER BY quality DESC LIMIT 5;
```

Context: the actual request is very CPU/time consuming, that's why I want to limit to one request if possible.

Comment: You could `union all` - that would return 10 rows in a single satatement.

Comment: Combining those two queries with `UNION ALL` is probably the most efficient solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a `WITH` clause to avoid writing the same code twice:

```
WITH my_complex_query AS (
    SELECT * FROM table_name
)
(SELECT * FROM my_complex_query ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 5)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM my_complex_query ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5)
```

Comment: Apparently the two last `SELECT` statements need to be enclosed by parentheses

Answer (score 0):

```
(SELECT * FROM table_name LIMIT 5) UNION (SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5);
```

Comment: A UNION ALL would be more efficient

Comment: Is it possible to not repeat the main request `SELECT * FROM table_name` ? The actual is complex, something like 60 lines of sql

Comment: Ah, thinking about `WITH` statement in order to not repeat, am I right?

Comment: The first subquery needs a dedicated ORDER BY as well. Because there is no specific sort order in tables, you might get any 5 records.